# Expression "Mind (you)"

Tags: vocabulary

Mind you means in a dictionary: "Used to make a sentese less strong or general"

For example - I'm lazy - I go to gym on Saturdays, mind you.

But, does "mind you" mean the same thing in these phrases?

1- **Don't be concerned about me, I'm good! Mind you**

2- **Tom can be here, mind**

Comment: Mind you is used in response to someone and comes at the beginning of a sentence. It does not come of nowhere. It is like an interjection. Mind how you go. :)

Comment: In the UK it doesn't always come at the start of a sentence and isn't always an interjection. Sometimes it's a synonym of "however" or "nevertheless".

Comment: You might want to look at a dictionary, mind.

Answer (score 0):

1. Should be **Don't be concerned about me, Mind you. I'm good!**

Although I cannot imagine anyone saying it. "Don't be concerned about me, I'm good!" would be normal.

2. Is wrong, where is the retort?

Examples

> He's very untidy about the house; mind you, I'm not much better.
>
> I know I'm lazy - I did go swimming yesterday, mind.[Link C.E.D.](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/mind-you?q=mind%20%28you%29)

Comment: I consider the use of this phrase quite old fashioned (and I am not young). Maybe it's a regional thing but I do not hear it used much.

Comment: I saw this in a game yesterday. And I use the dictionary  MacMillan and that second example  is from it

Comment: No it is not. Tom might be there, mind.is what it says in MacMillan

Comment: Yeah, that was what I meant when I wrote that comment.

Comment: @ThinkingBoi You saw it in a game but not like that at the end of a statement. You just made that up, cowboy.